# Python 3 Selenium Autofill

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to auto login on this site, but it doesn't autofill at all, here is my code.

I tried to search on Google, Youtube, saw very similar tutorials, followed each tutorial, but every time there is error or working without autofilling in username and password.

I would really appreciate if you could take a second and look at the following code and let me know what is the problem, why it doesn't work.

Any help much appreciated

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import unittest

class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe")
        self.driver.get("ts2.travian.si/login.php")

    def test_Login(self):

        driver = self.driver
        username = "FERIgeeks"
        password = "test123"
        usernameFieldName = "name"
        passwordFieldName = "password"
        loginButtonXpath = "//input[@value='Prijava']"

        usernameFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_name(usernameFieldName))
        passwordFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_name(passwordFieldName))
        loginButtonElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(loginButtonXpath))

        usernameFieldElement.clear()
        usernameFieldElement.send_keys(username)
        passwordFieldElement.clear()
        passwordFieldElement.send_keys(password)
        loginButtonElement.click()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Here are errors I get

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 601, in run
    testMethod()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Home\travianBot\travianBot.py", line 22, in test_Login
    loginButtonElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(loginButtonXpath))
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 71, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Home\travianBot\travianBot.py", line 22, in <lambda>
    loginButtonElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(loginButtonXpath))
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 309, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 787, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: target window already closed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
self.driver.get("ts2.travian.si/login.php")
```

to

```
self.driver.get("http://ts2.travian.si/login.php")
```

And look for the button for the id = "s1"

```
loginButtonXpath = "s1"

loginButtonElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(loginButtonXpath))
```